# Representations of finite group and base change of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of fields ($char=0$) and $G$ be a finite group. $V_i (i=1,2)$ are irreducible representation of $G$ over $K$. If $V_i \otimes_KL$ are isomorphic as representations over $L$, do we have $V_1 \cong V_2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $|L:K|=n$. Then $V_i\otimes_K L$ is an $LG$-module, but it is
still a $KG$ module, and is isomorphic to $V_i^n$ as $KG$-modules.
So $V_1\otimes_G L\cong V_2\otimes_G L$ over $L$ implies
$V_1^n\cong V_2^n$ over $K$.

As $KG$ is a finite-dimensional algebra over a field, the Krull-Schmidt
theorem holds for $KG$-modules. Each finitely generated module splits
as a direct sum of indecomposables, and in two such decomposition,
the number of factors isomorphic to each given indecomposable is
the same on each side.  It's now apparent that $V_1^n\cong V_2^n$
implies $V_1\cong V_2$.

Comment: Thanks, can we find an isomorphism $V_1 \cong V_2$ that induces the isomorphism of $V_i \otimes_K L$?

Comment: No, there are more isomorphisms in the latter case; consider for simplicity the special case that the $V_i$ are trivial.

Comment: Hi :) I was wondering if you used $char=0$ anywhere? Because when $char | |G|$ then $K[G]$ (and $L[G]$) is no longer semisimple and lots of funny stuff can happen.

In particular, an exercise in Jacobson's "Basic Algebra II" is to prove that if $K$ is an infinite field, and $L/K$ any extension, then if $L\otimes_K V_1\cong L\otimes_K V_2$ as $L[G]$-modules implies $V_1\cong V_2$ as $K[G]$-modules (where $V_1,V_2$ are finite dimensional representations). 

I thought the condition that the field were infinite was a necessary one but I fail to see where you're using it here. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOrtiz This trick does not use characteristic zero; neither does it use irreducibility of the original representations. All one needs is that $V_1$ and $V_2$ be finite-dimensional representations.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Do you happen to know what happens if $L/K$ is an infinite extension?  Then the $V\otimes L$ are no longer finitely generated as $K[G]$-modules so Krull-Schmidt does not apply. But some sources I've read claim the problem is still true as long as $K$ is infinite.

Comment: It's OK as long as $L/K$ is algebraic, as the isomorphism would be defined over a finite subextension. @JuanCarlosOrtiz